# What is wrong with my approach to Firebase here? What am I missing?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, server-side

I am looking for firebase support for my application. I have a web client talking with my server side Java components using rest calls. I want to give my users ability to login using any social media profiles. I have read java support for firebase here:

[Firebase user Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-providers)

1. I have created a firebase profile & a project under it.
2. Under that project I have enabled email / password authentication.
3. Then I have used the following code to create a dummy user.

   ```
   Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myappname.firebaseio.com");

   ref.createUser("bobtony @ firebase.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple", new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {

   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
   System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
     // there was an error
   }
   });
   ```

Code runs fine, no exceptions - but this code did not create a new user in firebase.

What did I miss? Did I need to do anything extra for this code to be able create a firebase user?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself*** see [mcve]

Comment: u should be more specific about what u want exactly .....i think this will help you.....http://bytefish.de/blog/fcmjava/

Comment: Basically mine is a web based application (say website, with java server side), not IOS not Android. I want to give users ability to login using any of those. I am planning to write a restful service to which they can send different login info and I validate the credentials. Any sample code will help